# How is "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header" a server issue if I can turn on a CORS extension and it works?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

- I access a server that I can change in any way. It is only available to me.
- GETS / POSTS work in curl, but I get an error in my angular web app
- I read a ton of posts about this, and after nothing seemed to work, I installed the [CORS extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) to Chrome, added `*://*/*`, and I have to turn it on anytime I'm trying to access the server. But it works.

Most of the posts say this is because the **server** does not allow access from outside sources. So I did some more digging and found [the W3 CORS enabled](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled) site, that specifies a filter must be added.

- However, when I get the error, I can open the network panel and see that the response came back exactly as I was expecting, so why did I get an error?

This makes it seem like Chrome is not allowing access.

- Why must the server be changed to allow this?
- Does this mean anyone with this chrome extension can access my server?
- It seems like it should be possible to configure a header in my $http.get that would allow this, but everyone keeps saying its the server...

Comment: For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from within scripts. This protects users from evil websites doing evilness. See [MDN Same Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy). See also [HTTP Access Control - CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

Comment: *"Does this mean anyone with this chrome extension can access my server?"* If you server is publicly available on the network, then yes. Also, anyone with curl, wget, Postman, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross domain calls are not allowed by default. When the browser makes a call to a website or Web-API sitting on a different domain than the domain opened on the browser, it includes a HTTP header "Origin" in the request. The server looks at this header and if it's white-listed it includes the header Access-Control_Allow_Origin in the response. All this happens in a pre-flight request using HTTP Options method before the actual GET/POST call.  So for the CORS to work the server has to allow the client domain, so the browser can make further calls.

Comment: FYI, pre-flight requests are only made for *non-simple* requests. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Simple_requests